# How to set Total Supply on TzKT?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft

I'm trying to create multi-edition items. My idea was to make a list of each token and then each token edition with the owner. Ok, i create the item and shows like that on blockchain: https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1Kzi3GnphcEb2v4WvKxBCFpZZxQD26jerK/bigmaps/data/keys

It shows exactly what i thought, but when i goes to TzKT to see the item, only show 1 created on supply. How can i set this to multi-edition?

The token on TzKT: https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1DSTBaxwdw7tm4MrRwNENpNsKv2bSuQRxX/tokens/0/transfers

What i want:
https://tzkt.io/KT1QgfSE4C1dX9UqrPAXjUaFQ36F9eB4nNkV/tokens/18/holders

Also the token metadata if helps: https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1DSTBaxwdw7tm4MrRwNENpNsKv2bSuQRxX/bigmaps/token_metadata/keys

My code:

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class Token(FA2.Admin, FA2.MintNft, FA2.Fa2Nft):
    def __init__(self, admin, **kwargs):
        FA2.Fa2Nft.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        FA2.Admin.__init__(self, admin)

class Marketplace(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, token, metadata, admin):
        self.init(
            token=token,
            metadata=metadata,
            admin=admin,
            data = sp.big_map(
                tkey=sp.TNat,
                tvalue=sp.TList(
                    sp.TRecord(
                        holder=sp.TAddress,
                        author=sp.TAddress,
                        amount=sp.TMutez,
                        token_id=sp.TNat,
                        editions=sp.TNat,
                        collectable=sp.TBool))),
            token_id=0)

    @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params):
        c = sp.contract(
            sp.TList(sp.TRecord(to_=sp.TAddress, metadata=sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes)).layout(("to_", "metadata"))),
            self.data.token,
            entry_point="mint").open_some()

        args = [sp.record(to_=params.to_, metadata=params.metadata)]
        sp.transfer(args, sp.mutez(0), c)

        editions_list = sp.local('editions_list', [])

        sp.for i in sp.range(1, params.editions + 1):
            edition_record = sp.record(
                holder=self.data.admin,
                author=params.to_,
                amount=params.amount,
                token_id=self.data.token_id,
                editions=i,
                collectable=True)
            
            editions_list.value.push(edition_record)

        self.data.data[self.data.token_id] = editions_list.value

        self.data.token_id += 1

@sp.add_test(name = "Non Fungible Token")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    
    admin = sp.test_account("admin")
    mark = sp.test_account("user1")
    elon = sp.test_account("user2")

    token_contract = Token(
        admin=admin.address,
        metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"))
    scenario += token_contract

    scenario.h1("MarketPlace")
    marketplace = Marketplace(
        token_contract.address,
        sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"
        ), admin.address)
    scenario += marketplace

    token_contract.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=admin.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://QmbR82U2yKHbhjve45rqSF9h25s5aFKhMcpZkLRvXRnos6")}
    ).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=mark.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        metadata={"": sp.pack("ipfs://bafyreibwl5hhjgrat5l7cmjlv6ppwghm6ijygpz2xor2r6incfcxnl7y3e/metadata.json")}
    ).run(sender=admin)
    
    marketplace.mint(to_=mark.address, amount=sp.mutez(5_600_000), editions=5, metadata={"": sp.pack("123423")}).run(sender=admin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a Semi-Fungible Token. `FA2.Fa2Nft` is not the correct class to use in this case. Try using `FA2.Fa2Fungible`. The reason is that TzKt understands the type of token by looking at the `ledger` of the token contract and some other things. So, using the `FA2.Fa2Fungible` class changes the ledger type to hold multiple tokens for a user for a token.

This will also change the way you mint, it has a separate mint params type. So, you will need to modify the other contract also.

The contracts will look like this:

```
import smartpy as sp

FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class Token(FA2.Admin, FA2.MintFungible, FA2.Fa2Fungible):
    def __init__(self, admin, **kwargs):
        FA2.Fa2Fungible.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        FA2.Admin.__init__(self, admin)

class Marketplace(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, token, metadata, admin):
        self.init(
            token=token,
            metadata=metadata,
            admin=admin,
            data = sp.big_map(
                tkey=sp.TNat,
                tvalue=sp.TList(
                    sp.TRecord(
                        holder=sp.TAddress,
                        author=sp.TAddress,
                        amount=sp.TMutez,
                        token_id=sp.TNat,
                        editions=sp.TNat,
                        collectable=sp.TBool))),
            token_id=0)

    @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params):
        c = sp.contract(
            sp.TList(
                sp.TRecord(
                    amount = sp.TNat,
                    to_ = sp.TAddress,
                    token = sp.TVariant(
                        existing = sp.TNat,
                        new = sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes)
                    ).layout(("existing", "new"))
                ).layout(("to_", ("token", "amount")))
            ),
            self.data.token,
            entry_point="mint").open_some()

        args = [
            sp.record(
                amount = params.editions,
                to_=params.to_,
                token=params.token
            )
        ]
        sp.transfer(args, sp.mutez(0), c)

        editions_list = sp.local('editions_list', [])

        sp.for i in sp.range(1, params.editions + 1):
            edition_record = sp.record(
                holder=self.data.admin,
                author=params.to_,
                amount=params.amount,
                token_id=self.data.token_id,
                editions=i,
                collectable=True)
            
            editions_list.value.push(edition_record)

        self.data.data[self.data.token_id] = editions_list.value

        self.data.token_id += 1

@sp.add_test(name = "Non Fungible Token")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    
    admin = sp.test_account("admin")
    mark = sp.test_account("user1")
    elon = sp.test_account("user2")

    token_contract = Token(
        admin=admin.address,
        metadata=sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"))
    scenario += token_contract

    scenario.h1("MarketPlace")
    marketplace = Marketplace(
        token_contract.address,
        sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
            "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"
        ), admin.address)
    scenario += marketplace

    token_contract.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=admin.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        token=sp.variant('new', {"": sp.pack("ipfs://QmbR82U2yKHbhjve45rqSF9h25s5aFKhMcpZkLRvXRnos6")})
    ).run(sender=admin)

    marketplace.mint(
        to_=mark.address,
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        editions=sp.nat(5),
        token=sp.variant('new', {"": sp.pack("ipfs://bafyreibwl5hhjgrat5l7cmjlv6ppwghm6ijygpz2xor2r6incfcxnl7y3e/metadata.json")})
    ).run(sender=admin)
    
    marketplace.mint(
        to_=mark.address,
        amount=sp.mutez(5_600_000),
        editions=5,
        token=sp.variant('new', {"": sp.pack("123423")})
    ).run(sender=admin)
```

These are the deployed contracts:

- Marketplace: https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1HpCGrkfxjBcDgZbtkV47bBgy4j1SRv5ZA/operations/
- Token: https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1DJWW8SnQtkoY2vyfPduhm9Ji36fW8MwE9/operations/

Comment: Thank you again, worked very well!!!
Just a question, when i'm gonna mint a new item(not a existing one), i need to set the next id right? And you know about any docs i can search for to learn more about Smartpy?

Comment: I already understood. I pass "new" before the object with { "" : bytes }, and "existing" if already exists.
Only more question, in sp.range of editions, why set holder to self.data.admin?

Comment: @borderlessdev No need to worry about the next ID in this case. There is already a `last_token_id` variable that takes care of that, by incrementing for every new mint. You may read the docs here https://legacy.smartpy.io/docs/guides/FA/FA2/overview.
For holders, I'm not sure... I just tried to keep it as similar as possible to your contract.

Comment: Ok, it's working fine. I'm trying to understand somethings, like, when i see token_metadata shows like this: "https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1XggGXMS79AqeyCNsWXjGspqdLcM9e9mg2/bigmaps/token_metadata/keys". Yeah, it's correct, each token with corresponding metadata, but when i look to the marketplace metadata shows like this: https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1VYx7pghH6z3rNeojZ2eXSV4kA6pkDK1QG/bigmaps/data/keys, as you can see, the token ID keeps rising when i try to mint a existing token, so my idea to transfer by ID and Edition fails here.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, you'll need to keep both the token ID in the token contract and marketplace contract in sync for the token ID. So, when a new token is minted we increase the token ID by one. But for existing mints, just increase the editions in the existing token ID data.